# Google-like full width sticky footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a footer like google uses on their home page at the bottom. It will be full width of the page with links on both sides. However, I would like to have a copyright in the center.

This is the default layout that I am using to acomplish this: http://jsfiddle.net/304gvLyn/

However, the footer is contained inside `container` so it doesn't span the full width of the page.

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
      <p class="text-muted pull-right">Button Here</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

If I turn that into `container-fluid` there is then no padding and it creates a horizontal scroll bar at times.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

This is what I am trying to do:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the following style rules on your footer? position: fixed; bottom: 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap containers are designed to be used with rows and columns.

```
<footer class="footer container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p class="text-muted pull-right">Button Here</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8 text-center">
            <p>Copyright Here</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p class="text-muted pull-right">Button Here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/304gvLyn/5)**

Answer (score -1):

You just have to tell that the container width have to take full width of the footer element:

```
.footer > .container{
    width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/304gvLyn/2/

Comment: Overwriting gird element styles should be a last resort. Bootstrap's grid accommodates full-width blocks as it is.